# Error occured while executing workflow in sharepoint2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a customed approval workflow created in visual studio 2010, after executing the task, there was an error occured in the task in SharePoint 2010.

How do you check error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to (Central Admin -> Monitoring -> Reporting -> Configure Diagnostic Logging) to check settings.

As far as I know the default location is "%programfiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\logs"